# A justified photo gallery with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create a justified photo gallery using flexbox. I set fixed row height: 250px and flex wrap.

```
body {
  width = 1100px; 
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery .img {
  height: 250px;
}
```

Now I'm facing the challenge when the row wrapped, each row has a different width, but I want them to have the same width.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/yunjuc/pen/dmoqZr?editors=1100) link. How can I modify the existing code to achieve my goal?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could you provide an image of the outcome you want? Thanks

Comment: Similar this this one - https://codesandbox.io/s/9yx911wl9y

Comment: Acutally, the number of images per row should change when screen size changes. So this is more close to what I want - https://codepen.io/yunjuc/pen/MVKrOj

Comment: The difference between your code and the example you provided is that you have images with different aspect ratios. If you give the images equal height, then to preserve aspect ratio they will have different widths. This makes lining up the rows challenging and you might need to use JavaScript. A quick google search returns this which may point you in the right direction: https://justifiedgrid.com/features/automatic-justified-layout/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 4):

After some further googling, there is a way to implement justified gallery with pure CSS, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Here is the source article: 
https://github.com/xieranmaya/blog/issues/6